# How to define getters on vuex module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to improve vuex module but getting error below:

```
Uncaught Error: [vuex] getters should be function but "getters.getComments" in module "comments" is [].
```

**/stores/comments.js** (module)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = {
    comments: []
}

const getters = {
    getComments: state => state.comments
}
const mutations = {
    setComments(state, comments) {
        state.comments = comments
    }
}

const actions = {
    setComments(context, data) {
        context.commit('setComments', data)
    }
}
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions
})
```

and here is my store.js that contains root state of the vuex
**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import commentsModule from './stores/comments'
Vue.use(Vuex);
const state = {
}

const getters = {
}

const mutations = {
}

const actions = {

}

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    modules: {
        comments: commentsModule
    },
    actions
})
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue. Tried but not understand what is the issue?

Comment: should not create a new `Store` inside a module file, and then export a new store to a supposedly the store itself.  the code of the store itself is missing.

Comment: @LiranC actually, its not missing. I didn't shared the store.js because it's only includes the module inside of it

Comment: i think you should include it, something is strange.

Comment: @LiranC I've add it on post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- You are creating `store` instance in `store.js` which is **good**
- You are creating **another** `store` instance inside `comment.js` which is **not good**

As a start, Try to Change the export block on `comment.js` to this:

```
export default {
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thats making sense but this time I am getting Cannot read property 'getComments' of undefined" error

Comment: maybe you have a typo? in the title you call your file 'comment.js' , and in the code you import comments.js

Comment: Actually, it's correct. I've just accidently typed in post

Comment: which line triggers the new error? what are you doing that generates the `undefined` error?

Comment: I think I am really confused now. Does it wrong to access getters of module like that: `this.$store.getComments` ?

Comment: try it this way:  `this.$store.getters.getComments`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157743/discussion-between-liranc-and-bl4cksta).

Answer (score 0):

Try this more modular way ;) :

Move your getters to an external module.

for example in `app/js/store/getters.js`:

```
export const getComments = state => {
    return state.comments;
};
```

And inside of `app/js/store/index.js` for example:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import * as getters from './getters';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        comments: [],
    },
    getters,
    // ...
});
```